# Jaccard index in python for a corpus using gensim

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, gensim

How do I use gensim to find out Jaccard index in vectors in the corpus?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
gensim.matutils.jaccard(vec1, vec2)
```

to calculate the Jaccard distance of two vectors. See also [gensim documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/matutils.html):

> gensim.matutils.jaccard(vec1, vec2)
>
> Calculate Jaccard distance between vectors. Parameters:
>
> ```
> vec1 ({scipy.sparse, numpy.ndarray, list of (int, float)}) – Distribution vector.
> vec2 ({scipy.sparse, numpy.ndarray, list of (int, float)}) – Distribution vector.
> ```
>
> Returns: Jaccard distance between vec1 and vec2. Value in range [0, 1], where 0
>   is min distance (max similarity) and 1 is max distance (min
>   similarity).
>
> Return type: float